# Litespeed error on RESTORE - works on 2005, fails on 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a 10 page procedure that will extract a litespeed compressed backup file (brought to Network shares from a different server) into 3 files, restores filelist and header; and then restores it to a local database.  When I try to run the procedure on a SQL Server 2008 server it fails with the following error whereas when run the same on a SQL Server 2005 server, it runs just fine and restores it to the local database.

> Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Full error:

```
Extracting differential LiteSpeed backup into SQL Server backup files: Started
Extracting differential LiteSpeed backup into SQL Server backup files: Complete
Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
```

Any thoughts on why it fails on SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the version of Litespeed you have (or your own stored procedure) is building a #temp table to dump the results of the `RESTORE` commands, and the code doesn't take version into account.

If you compare the [2005 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to the [2008 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for `RESTORE FILELISTONLY`, you'll see that 2008 added a new column called `TDEThumbprint` (there may be other changes; I didn't look very hard).

Similarly, comparing the [2005 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178536%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to the [2008 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178536%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for `RESTORE HEADERONLY`, there is an additional column called `CompressedBackupSize`.

The insert fails because the #temp tables being used to dump the results of this command are built for the 2005 version and are missing the additional column. SQL Server doesn't like it when a #temp table has 15 columns and you try to stuff 16 columns into it.

If it is your procedure that creates the #temp tables, you need to make your procedure branch depending on version, or create version-specific procedures, and use a table with the appropriate number of columns before running your insert.

If it is not your code, then you should talk to Dell/Quest about this. It's quite likely they have already fixed it, but you don't have the most recent version of Litespeed...

Comment: I found the same thing before reading this answer but thanks a lot for taking your time in answering this question!